# Uploading Image to php Server using OkHttp

Tags: android, file-upload, okhttp

I am trying to upload an image to the my [Server](http://rentmysport.com/api/v1/test/upload) with **POST** command. For that I am Using this code from [OkHttp Recipes](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#posting-a-multipart-request).

```
private static final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_JPG=MediaType.parse("image/jpg");
private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_equipment);
    PATH_TO_EXTERNAL = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    FULL_PATH = PATH_TO_EXTERNAL + IMAGE_PATH;
    file = new File(FULL_PATH);
    body = RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_JPG, file);

    run(); /* Calling it on Background Thread*/ 
}


public void run() throws Exception {

    RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBuilder().type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("aadcs", "acsd.jpg",body)
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(UPLOAD_URL).post(requestBody).build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    if (!response.isSuccessful()) { throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response); }

    Log.d("Response", response.body().string());
}
```

But the Problem is I am not able to get any response from this i.e when I debug the code line by line, it never goes beyond this line :
`Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();`.

Also the Url is working fine when I test it from any online REST CLients like [POSTMAN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en).
I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong here.

HELP!!!

Comment: are you sending any response from your server?

Comment: yes, I am sending Image File name.

Comment: when checked through "postman", it returns correct

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: I have tried the same thing and it has worked for me!

Comment: @SillyQuestions did you make it work?

Comment: [Follow this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795931/android-okhttp-adding-params/38990465#38990465). Hope it will help.

Comment: I guess you'd have fixed the problem by now, but for someone else with the same issue, I'd suggest setting timeout of the request to a few seconds.