# Android OKHttp adding params

Tags: android, okhttp

How is it possible to append params to an OkHttp Request.builder?

```
//request
Request.Builder requestBuilder = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url);
```

I've managed the add header but not params.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a complete example on how to use okhttp to make post request (okhttp3).

To send data as form body

```
RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
        .add("param_a", "value_a")
        .addEncoded("param_b", "value_b")
        .build();
```

To send data as multipart body

```
RequestBody multipartBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("fieldName", fileToUpload.getName(),RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"), fileToUpload))
            .build();
```

To send data as json body

```
    RequestBody jsonBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"),
            jsonObject.toString());
```

Now create request

```
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .addHeader("header_a", "value_a")  // to add header data
            .post(formBody)         // for form data
            .post(jsonBody)         // for json data
            .post(multipartBody)    // for multipart data
            .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

** fileToUpload is a object of type java File

** client is a object of type OkHttpClient

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you mean this:

```
 HttpUrl url = new HttpUrl.Builder().scheme("http").host(HOST).port(PORT)
            .addPathSegment("xxx").addPathSegment("xxx")
            .addQueryParameter("id", "xxx")
            .addQueryParameter("language", "xxx").build();
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this lib: https://github.com/square/mimecraft:**

```
FormEncoding fe = new FormEncoding.Builder()
    .add("name", "Lorem Ipsum")
    .add("occupation", "Filler Text")
    .build();
```

**Multipart content:**

```
Multipart m = new Multipart.Builder()
    .addPart(new Part.Builder()
        .contentType("image/png")
        .body(new File("/foo/bar/baz.png"))
        .build())
    .addPart(new Part.Builder()
        .contentType("text/plain")
        .body("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.")
        .build())
    .build();
```

**See here:**
[How to use OKHTTP to make a post request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23456488/how-to-use-okhttp-to-make-a-post-request)

Comment: How do I combine the two?

Comment: did you mean params and header?

Comment: Query parameters on the URL?